# How to design a stock system using Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

I have a project going on right now and need an SQL Database for this. This project is sort of like a stock system

Currently starting off I have done this:

```
Add -> New Item -> Service-Based Database 

Server Explorer -> Tables -> Add New Table -> Added in ID,Name,Price,Description  -> Update

Data Sources -> Add New Data Source -> Database -> Dataset -> Chose my database -> Checked Tables
```

Then I created Text boxes and Labels in Design

[These are my inputs for the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2UAJ.png)

I'd like to add the contents of these text boxes into the Database so that I can use these in the later part of the program but currently have no idea on how to do this. I have looked up many guides but they are all different or for older versions of Visual Basics which have features such as Entity that Visual Basics 2013 does not have. I have understood I need to connect the database, however I will be needing more help.

Finally, one of my inputs is an Image. I have currently saved the image into a variable however do not know how to input this variable into the database. 
I'd like to input everything in a way that I can take them out and store them in a listbox in a later part of the program.

Comment: I imagine the internet has plenty of step-by-step guides for VS already, and I wonder if it would be more efficient for you to find some of those, rather than have someone type article-length content here. You may find, indeed, that a book on the topic would be appropriate. Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your perspective) the broadness of this question means that it is not really a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have spent a long time trying to find these resources but as mentioned in  original post I've had no luck. I've decided to create this after weeks of not being able to solve this issue. Sorry if this doesn't fit Stack Overflow but I really didn't know where else to go.

Comment: For more discursive questions, you could try Reddit. A busy general learner's sub-forum [is this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/), though there's likely to be something for MS VS specifically - have a browse.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the links and help. I'll try making a post there if I cannot find anything by tomorrow. Hopefully this isn't the case. I've actually seen a lot of SQL help for MS VS however they all seem to be outdated in one way or extremely confusing (at least for me:p). The best I've found is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx which has gotten me to the point that I'm at now.